# TypeError: undefined is not a function at pipe in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to download a file from jira server and storing in my file but i am not able to store it in my file saying below error:

```
(data.body).pipe(fs.WriteStream('file.xlsx'));

          ^

TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

my nodejs code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser     =        require("body-parser");
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
require('ssl-root-cas/latest').inject();

var credentials = 'user:pass';
var encodedCredentials = new Buffer(credentials).toString('base64')

var url = ' https://gec-jira01.example.com/secure/attachment/IWREQ-373_update.xlsx';    

request({
    "method": "GET", 
    "rejectUnauthorized": false, 
    "url": url, 
    "headers" : {"Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic"+' '+encodedCredentials}
}, function(err, data, body) {
       //console.log(data);
       (data.body).pipe(fs.WriteStream('file.xlsx'));
       console.log(data.body);
)};
```

Comment: you should pipe the request, not the body. As:    `request({
method: "GET", 
"rejectUnauthorized": false, 
"url": url, 
"headers" : {"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "Basic"+' '+encodedCredentials}
}).pipe(fs.WriteStream('file.xlsx'));`

Comment: but data is in body how to make it trough request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
request({
    method: "GET", 
    "rejectUnauthorized": false, 
    "url": url, 
    "headers" : {"Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic"+' '+encodedCredentials}
}).pipe(
   fs.createWriteStream('file.xlsx')
);
```

or this:

```
request({
    method: "GET", 
    "rejectUnauthorized": false, 
    "url": url, 
    "headers" : {"Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic"+' '+encodedCredentials}
},function(err,data,body) {
   fs.WriteStream('file.xlsx').write(body);
});
```